# Not show disabled option elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I am wondering if there is a way to NOT show the disabled  elements? And if they we're re-enabled (by javascript/jquery) show them?

Comment: can show the script that you have been reach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it with a span that hides the element. Not pretty, but it works. E.g.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#togglebutton").click(function(){
    var Element=$("#disableme");

    if (Element.attr("disabled")==false) {
      Element.attr("disabled","disabled").wrap("<span class='hide'></span>");
    } else {
      Element.removeAttr("disabled");
      Element.parent('span.hide').replaceWith(Element.parent('span.hide').html());
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="disableme"><br />
<input type="button" id="togglebutton" value="Toggle disable">
```

Tested on IE 6, IE 8, Firefox 3.6.6, Opera 10.60 and Iron 5.0.380.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in jQuery, assuming you use the *proper* HTML attibrute for your `input` tags:

```
$('input[disabled="disabled"']).hide();
```

Then just add a `show()` to your jQuery code that re-enables them.

#### UPDATE

I failed to reference the question title. The above is a solution for form `input` tags, not select `option` tags.

Comment: will this work if I use a class selector? They have different classes.

Comment: @Nick, you sure? If this were CSS you'd be right. I'll have to check. @Steven, yes, simply add your class to the input: `input.yourclass[disabled="disabled"]`

Comment: He wants to hide `<option>` elements, not `<input>` you can't hide an `<option>` cross-browser :)

Comment: @Nick, ahhh. I tend to miss those things when it is only in the question title ;)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can do the following.

```
option[disabled]
{
    display:none;
}
```

Which should hide options that are disabled, not sure about browser compatibility.

Comment: Same as Jason's this won't work cross-browser, need a different approach for what the OP's after.

Comment: Well, it depends on what "cross-browser" means.  It works IE7+, Firefox 3+, Safari 3+, Chrome, and Opera 9+ - http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: The site needs to work in newish firefox ie 7+ and newish other ones.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said I wasn't sure about browser compatibility.

Comment: @Zurahn - That isn't true, it's not the `[disabled]` I was referring to, it's the `display: none;`  Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/BUNUL/